# How to solve this integral $\int \frac{2t^6+6t^4+t^3-3t-1}{t^9+3t^6+t^5+3t^3+t^2+1} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Good evening. I want some help to find the value of the integral

$$\int \frac{2t^6+6t^4+t^3-3t-1}{t^9+3t^6+t^5+3t^3+t^2+1} dt$$

Here is an overview of my attempts:

$1$. I tried dividing both numerator and denominator by $t^6$, thus obtaining

$$\int \frac{2+6\frac{1}{t^2} + \frac{1}{t^3} - 3\frac{1}{t^5} - \frac{1}{t^6}}{t^3 + 3 + \frac{1}{t} + 3\frac{1}{t^4} + \frac{1}{t^6}}dt$$

This got me nowhere.

$2$. I tried dividing both numerator and denominator by $t^3$. Then I obtained

$$\int \frac{2t^3+6t+1-\frac{3}{t^2} - \frac{1}{t^3}}{t^6+3t^3+t^2+3+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^3}}dt$$

I am clueless on how to proceed with the evaluation of this integral any further. It would be great if someone can provide some guidance for the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right path with the second approach. Note that:

$$ (2t^3+6t+1-\frac{3}{t^2} - \frac{1}{t^3}) dt = (t^2+\frac{1}{t} + 3)\cdot (2t -\frac{1}{t^2})dt$$

And

$$[t^6+3(t^2)^2\cdot \frac{1}{t} +3t^2 \cdot (\frac{1}{t^2})^2 +\frac{1}{t^3}]+(t^2+\frac{1}{t}) = (t^2+\frac{1}{t})^3+(t^2+\frac{1}{t})$$

Now let $$t^2+\frac{1}{t} = u$$

This implies that

$$ 2t - \frac{1}{t^2} = du$$

Then the integral simplifies into

$$\int \frac{u+3}{u^3+u}du = \int \frac{du}{u^2+1} + 3\cdot \int \frac{du}{u(u^2+1)} du = \arctan(u) + 3\cdot \int \frac{du}{u} - 3\cdot \int \frac{u}{u^2+1}du $$

$$ = \arctan(u) + 3\cdot \ln(u) - \frac{3}{2}\cdot \ln(u^2+1)$$

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, a fool-proof method (but quite brute force-y) is to factor the denominator into linear and quadratic polynomials and use partial fractions. Even if you cannot factor it into all quadratics and linears, it does reduce the degree of the denominator which might make it easier.

Here specifically, you can just check that $(t+1)$ and $(t^2-t+1)$ are factors of the denominator